# Creating Anonymous Pipe in Windows

Tags: c, windows, pipe

I just started learning about anonymous pipe communication. My question is what is the difference between AnonymousPipeStream and CreatePipe method.

Right now I am creating pipe with CreatePipe() and read/write data with ReadFile()/WriteFile() functions and it works fine.

But I see there are a lot of examples in the internet that create pipes completely in a different way using streams.

what is the advantage of each method? or they are not different methods and my understanding is wrong?

references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.io.pipes.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnonymousPipeClientStream` and `AnonymousPipeServerStream` are C# classes.  `CreatePipe` is the raw native API.  If you're coding in pure native C or C++, you cannot call into C# code (at least not without a fair amount of non-trivial work).